# Get OTP from USB YubiKey

Tags: android, usb, yubikey

I want to get OTP from a configured `yubikey`

I have access to the `UsbSession` and `UsbDevice` and `UsbManager`
But I'm not sure what to do to get the OTP

Do you have suggestions?

Comment: Doesn't simply touching the "button" solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, in order for the yubikey to get data from usb, you need to have a hidden edittext on the screen to get the input event from the yubikey.